# Web Scraping with python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape https://sparrow.eoffice.gov.in/IPRSTATUS/IPRFiledSearch and download the entire set of PDF files that show up in the search results as  on date (say 01-01-2016). The employee fields are optional. On clicking search, the site throws up a list of all the employees. I am unable to get the post method to work using python requests. Keep getting a 405 error. My code is below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://sparrow.eoffice.gov.in/IPRSTATUS/IPRFiledSearch"

data = {
    'assessmentYearId':'vH4pgBbZ8y8rhOFBoM0g7w',
    'empName':'',
    'allotmentYear':'',
    'cadreId':'',
    'iprReportType':'cqZvyXc--mpmnRNfPp2k7w',
    'userType':'JgPOADxEXU1jGi53Xa2vGQ',
    '_csrf':'7819ec72-eedf-4290-ba70-6f2b14cc4b79'
}

headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length':'184',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the website but I strongly suggest reading their policy before trying to scrape the content.

In similar scenarios when you don't get the expected results by a simple post, using `requests.Session` usually helps.

Comment: i modified the code to use sessions but its not working .

urlpage = "https://sparrow.eoffice.gov.in/IPRSTATUS/IPRFiledSearch"
urlpost = "https://sparrow.eoffice.gov.in/IPRSTATUS/iprStatus/doSearchEmployee"

session = requests.Session()
page = session.get(urlpage)
post = session.post(urlpost,data=data,headers=headers)

Comment: Web scraping can get quite tricky sometimes. Use Chrome's developer tools to precisely simulate the request and consider using Selenium if you're not using your code in production.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in my using the same csrf code. Needs to be changed with every request.